# .NET Core vs Classic: differences compiling generic type. Error: "The type '..' is defined in an assembly "

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, visual-studio-2017, assembly-references

We have three assemblies:

Assembly1 (Standard)

```
public class ClassParent{

}
```

Assembly2 (Standard) references Assembly1

```
public class ClassChild: ClassParent{

}
```

Assembly3 (uses Shared project) references Assembly2

```
public interface IGeneric<T>{
}

public class GenericClass: IGeneric<ClassChild>{

}
```

Uses "Shared project" means that whole solution contains 5 projects "Assembly1",  "Assembly2", "Assembly3 (Shared Project)", "Assembly3 Core target ",  "Assembly3 Classic NETFremework target".

And compiling them in Visual Studio 2017

**If target is Core**, then compilation **OK**.
But **when target is classic** .NETFramework we get an **error**:

> Error CS0012  The type 'ClassParent' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly ''.

It is interesting that compiled Core assembly doesn't contain reference to Assembly1 (dotPeek disasm).

Therefore  I can't explain what is a reason of the Core success: compiler by itself or Visual Studio tooling that manage compilation.

Anyway, can we do something with this "error" and force Visual Studio  to compile assmebly for .NETFramework ?  Without adding "direct" reference (to save reference list clear).

UPDATE:

Why I do not want to add additional reference: because in real life case it is an Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore that brings together a twenty additional references and after it reference list will include every .NET Standard library (means references list loose its informative meanings).

Comment: `If target is Core, then compilation OK` - Which target? You mentioned you have 3 different assemblies and of course each will have its own target(s).

Comment: Compilation of Assembly3 (files are defined in shared project)

Answer (score 1):

For libraries to be shared between .NET Framework 4.5+ and .NET Core 1.0+, you need to those libraries to target [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard). Of course, .NET Standard assemblies can only consume other .NET Standard assemblies, so this implies you would have to target .NET Standard for all of your nested dependencies no matter how deep in the graph they are.

Do note that .NET Standard cannot be used for *executables* though, for those you need to target one (or more) of the platforms that .NET Standard can consume (.NET Framework, .NET Core, Xamarin.iOS, etc).

```
Assembly3 (netstandard2.0) -- (Shared Project)
      \
     Assembly2 (netstandard2.0)
         \
         Assembly1 (netstandard2.0)
```

`Assembly1`, `Assembly2` and `Assembly3 (Shared Project)` only need target .NET Standard.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...

</Project>
```

The other 2 projects can then simply reference the .NET Standard class libraries.

### Conditional Dependencies

If you want to multi-target with conditional dependencies, for example, if `Assembly1` should be referenced from `Assembly3` when target framework is .NET Core, but not be included when target framework is .NET Framework, you can use [MSBuild conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions) in a multi-targeted project.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;net462</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- non-conditional reference for all target frameworks -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Assembly2\Assembly2.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- conditional references that only apply to netcoreapp2.0 -->
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.0' ">
    <!-- for projects within the same solution -->
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Assembly1\Assembly1.csproj" />

    <!-- for NuGet references -->
    <PackageReference Include="System.Globalization.Extensions" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Note that Visual Studio doesn't contain any tools to help you manage such conditions, you have to hand edit the project files to manage them. In Visual Studio 2017, you can just right click on the project node in Solution Explorer and click `Edit <TheProjectName>.csproj` to open the editor.

Comment: yes, situation is more complicated. Assembly1 and Assembly2 are Standard. Assembly3 sources defined in shared project.

Comment: It changes `Assembly1` and `Assembly2` so they can be consumed by both .NET Core and .NET Framework. If they are targeting .NET Framework, they are not recognized by .NET Core (hence the error message). You will also get a similar error message if your assemblies target .NET Core and you try to consume them with .NET Framework.

Comment: But I just want to save reference list the same clear  for .NET Framework taget as for .NET Core target. Does multitargeting help with this?

Comment: I added what the `.csproj` project files should look like. Hopefully that makes it more clear. Of course the `...` sections should be removed and replaced with real XML of your projects.

Comment: Thank you NigthOwl. My Assembly1  and Assembly2  are allready Standard (Assembly3 is shared project and shared between two target assmeblies). My problem is not how to "organize" solution but how to explain why in case of .NET Framework I should add addtional reference to target assembly and can be this avoided (in real case I will need to add a lot of assemblies).

Comment: Since you are targeting 2 different platforms (.NET Core and .NET Framework), the general advice is to make all of your shared assemblies .NET Standard. The executables must target your specific platform (and do note .NET Console DLLs and ASP.NET DLLs are executable).

Comment: But it is unclear what you mean by "additional reference to target assembly", exactly.

Comment: That means:  the Assembly1 should be referenced (in Assembly3) when target (for Assembly3 ) is .NET Framework  when in case of Assmble3 compiled for target .NET Core the Assembly1 reference is not required. It is hardly expected, I agree. 

I would like to get an explanation of this and to learn is it possible to manage MSBuild somehow that reference to Assembly1 would not be required (to keep reference list clear for understanding).

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij - I updated my answer to show an example of a conditional dependency in a multi-targeted project.

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't explain why core compilation is more clever then classic, but definitly shows the way how it can be managed for multitargeting.